# How to properly encrypt information using Core Data

Tags: database, core-data, encryption

I'm developing an app that manages sensitive information. For this reason I would like to give the user the option of creating a password to encrypt the data. This information is only to be saved in the device; the idea is not to encrypt and send the data through a network, but to prevent other people with total access to the device to have access to it.

Now, what I don't know is if I should encrypt the whole data base or encrypt only each entry before saving it. What is the recommended approach to encrypt data bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diego,

Encrypting data is a subtle problem.

First, do the easy stuff. Turn on Apple's file security. That will probably give you more security for less effort than anything you can write. It probably provides all of the security you really need on the device. If it doesn't, you should know exactly what it doesn't provide. That would be the main cause for writing special purpose code. Apple recently posted an excellent white paper on iOS security. We all should read it.

Second, security is broken in subtle and non-obvious ways. It just isn't a matter of firing up the encryption and then hoping for the best. How are you going to handle key distribution to other devices? How are you going to handle lost keys? Do you trust Apple's keychain? (Have they fixed their process in the wake of "goto fail;"?)

The way most security folks I know handle these issues is by building detailed scenarios of use. And then implementing code to see if the design is any good. Then asking their friends and consultants to poke holes in the design; fix the holes until you have "confidence" in your design. If you are new to security, and by the nature of your question I assume you are relatively new to the field, then you should *NOT* have confidence in your design. You now need to reimplement your design with simpler code and simpler processes. Then put it in front of real users. They will show you how your security process fails in real hands. Bad security design has killed many products and it can kill yours.

I would be very careful. Use what Apple has already carefully engineered. Seriously ask yourself if you need more than that. Ask your management how much they want to spend on security? Ask your users how important the bother of security is for them? I suspect the answer to both questions is: no, they do not want to pay for or bother with security.

As a result, do the simple stuff: use Apple's iOS security.

Anon,
Andrew